# How to change background color while swiping on an view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-gesture

I Have an relative layout and on this relative layout I handled the swiping from right to left and from left to right events successfully using the following code.

```
    relativeLayout1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gesture.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });


final GestureDetector gesture = new GestureDetector(getActivity(),
        new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

            @Override
         public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
         public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {return true;}
         public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {}
         public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {return true;}
         public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {return true;}
         public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {}
         public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {return true;}
         public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {return true;}
            @Override
         public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {

                final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 5;
                final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 400;
                final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 100;
                try {
                    if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                        return false;
                    if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE// user slide right to left
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                        Log.i("Mhd", "Right to Left");

                    } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE//user slide left to right
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                        Log.i("Mhd", "Left to Right");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
                return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
            }  
        });
```

But I really need the color of relative layout change based on where my finger arrived while I am swiping on this relative layout for example when you try to call some one your android device you will swipe from left to right and you will notice that the color changes based on where your finger arrived on contact view.

Comment: doesn't setBackgroud[Drawable]() work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example exactly look like Samsung devices which swipe from left to right and the color changes based on where your finger arrived on contact view. and swipe right to left to send message

First, your XML for this part should look like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/YourRelativeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1.27"
android:background="#234c5e"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/slideColorFromLiftToRightLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/color_green"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/slideColorFromRightToLiftLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/yalow"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

then you can use this fragment of code to check the direction of slide and change the width of colored layout.

```
    int x1,x2,x3,halfOfWidth = 0;
YourRelativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Log.d("Mhd", "ACTION_MOVE:event.getX() =============> " + event.getX());
                Log.d("Mhd", "ACTION_MOVE:event.getRawX() " + event.getRawX());

                x2 = (int) event.getRawX();

                if (x1 < halfOfWidth && x2 > x1) {
                    /// here check if there user slide from lift to write
                    slideColorFromLiftToRightLayout.requestLayout();
                    slideColorFromLiftToRightLayout.getLayoutParams().width = (int) event.getX();
                }

                if (x1 > halfOfWidth && x2 < x1) {
                    slideColorFromRightToLiftLayout.requestLayout();
                    slideColorFromRightToLiftLayout.getLayoutParams().width = (halfOfWidth * 2) - (int) event.getX();
                }
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                // this event occure after the user release his finger

                   x3 = (int) event.getX();
//                    slideColorFromLiftToRightLayout.getLayoutParams().width = 0; to clear the color of L to R
//                    slideColorFromRightToLiftLayout.getLayoutParams().width = 0; to clear the color of R to L
                    return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
              // when user put his finger on screen
                x1 = (int) event.getX();
                halfOfWidth = AnswerRelativeLayout.getWidth() / 2;
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use a selector xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_background_normal"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_background_touched" android:state_hovered="true"/>    
</selector>
```

Comment: Sorry but Where can I place this fragment of code ?

Comment: create a XML file in "drawable" folder, e.g. namely "button_background.xml", then set android:background="@drawable/button_background" in the RelativeLayout you want to apply this behaviour

Comment: Thank you for replay. I did as you write just the background change and not this that I want. But I want while swiping on Relative layout, change the background color of the place under and before my finger like when you try to swipe from left to right to call some one from your contact in your android device.